# Pra que serve exatamente o modificador "u"?

Tags: php, regex, utf-8

O que faz exatamente o modificador `u` nas expressões regulares de `preg_` em `PHP`?

É recomendável usá-lo sempre que for processar strings que possuem caracteres com acentuação?

```
$valor = 'ãẽi ouã';
preg_match('/\w+/u', $valor, $matches);

$matches; // 'array(2) { ãẽi, ouã}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Este modificador `/u` é para suporte unicode.

Por exemplo se deseja fazer uma `regex` com palavras em japonês é necessário usa-lo.

```
preg_match('/[\x{2460}-\x{2468}]/u', $str);
```

Onde `\x{hex}` - é um `char-code` hexadecimal UTF-8.

Executando a seguinte regex:

```
$valor = 'ãẽi ouã';
preg_match('/\w+/u', $valor, $matches);
```

retorna:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    0 => 'ãẽi',
    1 => 'ouã',
  ),
)
```

Executando a seguinte regex (sem o modificador):

```
$valor = 'ãẽi ouã';
preg_match('/\w+/', $valor, $matches);
```

retorna:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    0 => '�',
    1 => '��',
    2 => 'i',
    3 => 'ou�',
  ),
)
```

Não se deve utilizar para pegar vogais acentuadas exemplos:

```
$valor = 'ãẽi ouã';
preg_match('/a/u', $valor, $matches);
```

retorna:

```
array (
 0 => 
  array (
  ),
)
```

Site para testes: [Link](https://pt.functions-online.com/preg_match_all.html)

Documentação: [Link](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php)

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. Modifiquei um trecho da segunda pergunta, porque achei importante para a dúvida. Eu na verdade queria dizer Se tenho que usar sempre o "u" quando eu for analisar palavras que tenha acentuações (utf-8 engloba muita coisa)

Comment: @WallaceMaxters ok irei dar uma complementada

Comment: @WallaceMaxters editei